# How to install modules in node_modules folder of electron app keeping them isolated from other modules present in node_modules folder..?

Tags: node.js, electron, puppeteer

I am trying to make a webscrapping app using node js and electron. My app directory contains package.json file. So
When i run "npm install electron --sav-dev". It successfully installed electron in the root node_modules folder. Again when i run "npm install puppeteer", it successfully installed puppeteer in the root of node_modules folder. But this deletes several folders related to electron and the app stops functioning. So please help me how can i install modules in node_modules folder keeping them isolated from other modules..

[image - Directory of my electron app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYcwW.jpg)
[image- Electron installed in node_modules folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBKTx.jpg)